# How do I use scala collection methods to make a method for correlation coefficient?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I'm using the sample correlation coefficient formula from this website: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient

Formula:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzkm8.png]

How do I even sum up each x and y value from the list individually? This is all I have so far:

```
  def correlation[T](elements: List[T], property1: T => Double, property2: T => Double): Double = {
    val xValues = elements.map(property1)
    val yValues = elements.map(property2)
    val Sx = standardDeviation(xValues, property1)
    val Sy = standardDeviation(yValues, property2)
    val xSize = xValues.size.toDouble
    val ySize = yValues.size.toDouble
    val xMean = xValues.sum / xSize
    val yMean = yValues.sum / ySize
    (1/xSize-1) * (xValues.map(x => x - xMean) * yValues.map(y => y - yMean)).sum
 }
```

So, for example, we have the data set is List((2,7), (8,12), (11,17))

x̅ would be 7 ((2+8+11)/3= 7). y̅ would be 12 ((7+12+17)/3=12).

I'm trying take each x values and minus x̅ from each of them. This gives us, (2-7)= -5; (8-7)= 1; (11-7)= 4. Same for y values, (7-12)= -5; (12-12)=0; (17-12)=5.

And multiply each of the x values and y values gives us, (-5*-5)= 25; (1*0)= 0; (4*5)=20.

Adding up each of these gives us, (25+20)=45

But I can't seem to get the multiplication part of each x and y values before summing. Would I need a recursion for this?

Edit: I have a separate method for calculating the standard deviation

Comment: Does this help? https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-pearson-correlation-score-algorithm-programming-collective-intelligence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line ought to be

```
xValues.zip(yValues).map { case (x, y) => (x - xMean) * (y - yMean) }.sum
```

This is very close to the other answer, with the added detail that, when `map`ping, we need to use `case` to take apart the tuple created by `zip`. This must be done because `map` takes only one parameter, while `(x, y) => ...` is a function with two parameters.

Another valid approach would have been:

```
xValues.zip(yValues).map(pair => (pair._1 - xMean) * (pair._2 - yMean)).sum
```

Where `_1`and `_2` access an item in the tuple.

Note that this applies to Scala 2.x, Scala 3 will support [parameter untupling](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the zip function:

```
xValues.zip(yValues).map((x, y) => (x - xMean) * (y - yMean)).sum
```

(sorry if the syntax is wrong, have not been programming in scala for years)